x86_64 - Using GDB on a code assembled with GAS causing strage error
I have this code written in Assembly x86_64:
.section .data
.equ SYS_CALL, $0x80
.set filename, "a.txt"
 
.section .text
.section .bss
.lcomm buffer, 20
 
.globl _start
_start:
  mov $1,%rbx #this instruction does not matters, I just added it so it won't be blank

After assembling (with GAS) and linking it, I inserted it into GDB, then executed:
(gdb) break *_start

and the output was:

'_start' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type

I couldn't find anything related, but it seems that if I'm removing the .bss section I can debug it fine. Now I wonder if I have to switch to the NASM compiler (is it better?).

.bss is not an executable section. Put your code into .text. You need to move the .section .text to before the .globl _start. Also note that .lcomm automatically puts the thing into .bss so you don't even have to write .section .bss Likely .set filename, "a.txt" will not do what you think either. +1 for using gdb though :)

@Jester
Oh, that workd. that was so dumb of me. Thank you so much! And yeah, I saw that .set filename, "a.txt" didn't work as I expected, I assume I have to research more about how to do it
